# Entity framework Code First: select data from table with discriminator

Tags: .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

First sorry if my title is not clear, but I do have hard time putting it as simple sentence in English :).

Let's say I have a website that manages, people and super heroes, I have 2 classes:

```
 public class Person
    {      
        [Key]
        public int PersonId { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string Name { get; set; }    
    }

  public class SuperHero:Person
    {    
        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string SuperHeroName { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<SuperPower> SuperPowers{ get; set; }
    }
```

In my database I have this:

Person 1: Id = 1 Name ="Alex Flimster" Discrimiator= "Person"

Person 2 : ID = 2 Name="Bruce Wayne" discriminator="SuperHero" SuperHeroName="Batman"

I know if I do :

```
var test = from Context.Person select p;
```

I get everyone, hero or not.

If i want only hero I would do:

```
var test = from Context.Person.OfType<SuperHero>() select p;
```

My question is this: How do I get only the person?

```
var test = from Context.Person.OfType<Person>() select p;
```

Will return the same as first test.

**Edit**
I guess my question is not totally clear.
Let's say I have 200 Person, and on top of that 10 superhero. I need a query that would return all Person that are just person and none of the possible heritant classes. 
(Let's say I have another class 'VideoGame Hero' that inherit from person as well. I would need a simple query that would be just person and none of the other classes)

Thanks!

Comment: Just for clarification, you are saying you want Persons who are not superheroes?

Comment: Yes, that's it, i just want Person and none of the possible heritant classes (let's say person is herited by SuperHero and employee( dummy example)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this

```
from p in Context.Person
where !(p is SuperHero)
select p
```

Or fluent one

```
Context.Person.Where(p => !(p is SuperHero))
```

UPDATE: SQL will look like:

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[Discriminator] AS [Discriminator], 
[Extent1].[PersonId] AS [PersonId], 
[Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
[Extent1].[SuperHeroName] AS [SuperHeroName]
FROM [dbo].[Person] AS [Extent1]
WHERE ([Extent1].[Discriminator] IN (N'SuperHero',N'Person')) 
      AND ([Extent1].[Discriminator] <> N'SuperHero')
```

Comment: I'm really curious about SQL generated by that query :)

Comment: Good call :). Now let's say Person is inherited by 2 classes 'SuperHero' and 'VideoGameHero', I would like a direct query and not write where.( p=>!((p is SuperHero) || !p is Employee)) (if possible) Thanks :)

Comment: @Tom I don't think you can access discriminator column - it is used internally be EF (like in sample above). So, you need either filter out all types manually, or write something like in this blog [How to write OfTypeOnly<TEntity>()](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/09/17/tip-35-how-to-write-oftypeonly-tentity.aspx)

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy How would you modify this (fluent syntax) to also include the `ICollection<SuperPower> SuperPowers`?

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy your link is out of date :) But nonetheless useful information.