# Entity framework code first - select objects from table, where type of the object is within a predefined list

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Using Entity Framework, I have a hierarchy of classes, which map to the same table. Something like `Cat : Animal`, `Dog : Animal`, `Goat : Animal`.

Of course EF internally uses the Discriminator column to handle them.

Now, I want to write something like:

```
var houseAnimals = new List<Type>(new [] { typeof(Cat), typeof(Dog) });
this.dataRepository.Animals.Where(a => houseAnimals.Contains(a.GetType()));
```

Naturally this won't work, as LINQ-to-SQL does not support `.GetType()`. However, this would work:

```
this.dataRepository.Animals.Where(a => a is Cat);
```

I don't want to do `a is Cat || a is Dog` because this list is dynamically built at runtime.

Based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15772814/entity-framework-code-first-select-data-from-table-with-discriminator), I understand that EF will convert it to a SQL query which features a 'Discriminator in' statement. So, this gives my some hope that what I need can be done. This:

```
this.dataRepository.Animals.Where(a => a is **in** houseAnimals);
```

would be nice, but of course there is no such syntax.

Question is, what syntax could I use to achieve this? Am I missing something here? Is this a missing functionality in EF? I can't be the only one who has ever wanted to do such query.

Please don't ciritize my approach and the need of doing this query, based on this example, as I have simplified it a lot just for the purpose of explaining what I need. Doing `.ToList()` is also not an option.

Comment: I would be very weary of Discriminator columns if I were you, and only use them if you really really need to. SQL has relationships - primary and foreign keys - trying to use this kind of inheritance mapping can cause you all sorts of problems

Comment: I don't use the Discriminator column, explicitly.

Comment: Okay, let me rephrase - I would be very weary of using C# object inheritance mapping in SQL.

Comment: That's the default way EF code first works. Package Manager Console generates the SQL scripts for me and it decides to use a single table for my classes + Discriminator. I am not in posiiton to criticize it ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EF does not provide such functionality out of the box. But it's not hard to write a custom extension method that builds the predicate dynamically with the help of the [`Expression.TypeIs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.typeis(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`Expression.OrElse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353063(v=vs.110).aspx) like this:

```
public static class QueryableExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<T> OfType<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, IEnumerable<Type> types)
    {
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "a");
        var body = types
            .Select(type => Expression.TypeIs(parameter, type))
            .Aggregate<Expression>(Expression.OrElse);
        var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, parameter);
        return source.Where(predicate);
    }
}
```

Assuming your repository returns `IQueryable<Animal>`, the usage will be:

```
this.dataRepository.Animals.OfType(houseAnimals);
```

Comment: I know I'm supposed to avoid comments like +1 but I have to say this is an impressive solution and it worked for me.

Comment: The repository exposes `IDbSet<Animal> Animals` actually. I am having trouble using your code - `no overload for method 'OfType' takes 1 argument`.

Comment: `OfType` with one argument is the method in the answer. Make sure the extension method is visible in the place where you need it. i.e. `using {the namespace containing above class};`.