# Get only objects of specified type (without derivation)

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, orm, entity-framework-6

I have such class structure

```
public class Aclass { ... }
public class Bclass : Aclass { ... }
public class Cclass : Bclass { ... }
```

I try to get all data (by EF6) passing some condition and be only of type Bclass.

```
_dbContext.Aclasses
    .Where(condition)
    .Where(p => p is B)
    .ToList();
```

But my query download also object which are Cclass objects(I understand it's ok). I can add condition for

```
.Where(p is Bclass && !(p is Cclass))
```

but if I decide in future to add next derivation class I'll need to change such code.

My question is: how can I determine in EF query to get only specified objects, without derived objects?

Comment: Have you read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15853159/isassignablefrom-isinstanceoftype-and-the-is-keyword-what-is-the-difference? In your case simply compare the types: `p.GetType() == typeof(B)`.

Comment: If you want the filtering done in the database, EF TPH makes use of a [Discriminator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7393788/entity-framework-code-first-creates-discriminator-column) which you can surely use as in the where predicate?

Comment: @StuartLC discriminator is not accessible on your model. Maybe creating a SQL view and map it to your entity.

Comment: Unfortunately the only supported operator in L2E queries is `is`, so what you are asking is not possible.

Comment: [This answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15772948/314291) analyses the generated Sql - seemingly the using `is` maps down to a Sql where on an `IN` clause of all Subtypes, as per Ivan's comment.

Comment: @HimBromBeere: typeof(T) is not supported by EF,

Comment: @StuartLC how can I use discriminator in LINQ where statement?

Comment: @Jacek That's the problem - you can't (EF hides it and does not allow you accessing it in the queries. Unnecessary over-encapsulation as most of the EF6 things).